# What is the simplest way to print a series of full-page images from a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, printing, xps

I have a series of images (just stored locally on disk) that I would like to print, one-per-page, possibly scaled up/down if necessary and centered.

What is the most straightforward method of doing this from a WPF application?

Is it to somehow create an XPS document and if so then how? If not, what other possibilities are there? (e.g. `PrintDocument` from `System.Drawing`?)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PrintDialog.PrintVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx) to print anything that derives from System.Windows.Media.Visual, for example a `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas`, or a `System.Windows.Controls.Image`.

```
PrintDialog dlg = new PrintDialog();
if (dlg.ShowDialog())
{  
  dlg.PrintVisual(visualCtrl); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I found [Open-Source .NET WPF Reporting Engine](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/). I didn't try it, but I expect it can do images, and on home page it says it can do XPS.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The comment "This is a very early alpha version not intented to be used in production environments" scares me since we are going into beta in the near future. I will definitely keep an eye on it. The WinForms way of using PrintDocument currently seems like the easiest solution.